# airflow trigger rule 'none_failed' doesn't work

Tags: python, airflow

I have a workflow below. What I want to do is to run the `join` task if all parents in success or skipped state. For this I use `none_failed` trigger rule, but have a problem when all upstream tasks in `skipped` state, so downstream task `join` is skipped automatically. Is there any solution, so I can run `join` task if all parents are `skipped`? Trigger rule `all_done` doesn't fit for me.
[Airflow workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ34c.png)

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id="branch_without_trigger",
    schedule_interval="@once",
    start_date=dt.datetime(2019, 2, 28),
)


def fun():
    raise AirflowSkipException("exception")


run_this_first = DummyOperator(task_id="run_this_first", dag=dag)
branching = DummyOperator(task_id="branching", dag=dag, python_callable=fun)

branch_a = DummyOperator(task_id="branch_a", dag=dag)
follow_branch_a = PythonOperator(
    task_id="follow_branch_a", dag=dag, python_callable=fun
)

branch_b = PythonOperator(task_id="branch_b", dag=dag, python_callable=fun)

join = DummyOperator(task_id="join", dag=dag, trigger_rule="none_failed")

run_this_first.set_downstream(branching)
branching >> branch_a >> follow_branch_a >> join
branching >> branch_b >> join
```